# Return LINQ Query and INSERT Data

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I need to grab data from a table (Job) and copy that data into the corresponding columns on another table (JobDetails). I'm running a LINQ query that gets the data from the (Job) table that I will need to insert into the JobDetails table here:

```
 //Run query to get a list of all tasks that have the group ID passed
        IQueryable<Task> TasksQuery =
            from c in db.Tasks
            select c;
    //Execute and loop results...
    IQueryable<Task> TasksByGroupId = TasksQuery.Where(c => c.TaskGroupId == TasksGroupId);

    //TODO: Insert the results or list from above as a new JobDetails row
```

Now I'm at a complete and total loss in terms of extracting this data and inserting it back into specific columns on my JobDetails Table. I've tried doing a .ToList() in an attemp to create a readable list but I'm sure there is a more effective way of doing this. I would like to be able to one column at a time assign a variable and insert it into the corresponding row of my JobDetails table.

**EDIT: Added Classes**

```
public partial class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ClosedDate { get; set; }
    public string ClosedBy { get; set; }
    public string Revision { get; set; }
}

public partial class JobDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TaskId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TaskIdOrder { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TimeCompleted { get; set; }
    public string CompletedBy { get; set; }
    public string Revision { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT: Added Task Class**

```
public partial class Task

{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public int TaskGroupId { get; set; }
    public int TaskOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does `JobDetails` not have a reference back to the `Job` (e.g. a foreign key)?  Are you using Entity Framework, or some other LINQ tool?

Comment: Entity and I have a foreign key from the Job Id to the JobDetails JobId - is the correct solution to add more foreign key relationships?

Comment: So does your `JobDetails` class not have a mapped property back to the `Job`?  Example: `public Job Job { get; set; }` using that foreign key.  I think you should post your entity framework mappings, it sounds like that is where you need the most help.

Comment: I've added those above.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding your problem. are you just needing the `Id` from `Job` to fill in the `JobId` on `JobDetail`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not explaining my problem the best. I will reword my question in a moment. Basically I'm selecting all the rows in my **Tasks** table that have the same "TaskGroupId" - In this result I'm getting the values "Id" and "TaskOrder" those are the only two columns that I need to pass into the **JobDetails** Table. At this point I'm getting the full list and now I'm needing to insert the data into the **JobDetails** table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var task in TasksByGroupId)
{
    db.JobDetails.AddObject(new JobDetail()
        {
            TaskId = task.Id,
            TaskIdOrder = task.TaskOrder
        });
}

db.SaveChanges();
```